# React Material UI MUI 'MuiDialog-container' remains visible (and blocking) after the close of the dialog, when the dialog is implemented as component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

I have employee search dialog, that I would like to use from the multiple places of my React app. E.g. my component is:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import { TextField, Input } from '@mui/material';

const DialogCheck = ({ id, employee: initialEmployee, active, onCancel, onSelect }) => {

    /*
    useEffect(() => {
        alert("Report: " + JSON.stringify(active));
    }, [active]); */

    const handleClose = () => {
        //What can I do here?
    };

    const handleCancel = () => {
        onCancel();
    };

    const handleSelect = () => {
        onSelect();
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog open={active} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title" scroll="body">
                <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Data search</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText>
                        To select an employee, please, search and click Select
                    </DialogContentText>
                    <Input
                        autoFocus
                        margin="dense"
                        sized="small"
                        variant="filled"
                        value="somehting..."
                        fullWidth
                    />
                    <TextField
                        autoFocus
                        margin="dense"
                        id="name"
                        label="Somehting..."
                        type="something..."
                        fullWidth
                    />
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleCancel} color="primary">
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={handleSelect} color="primary">
                        Select
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}

export default DialogCheck;
```

This component can be placed into multiple places of the app and the warpping/parent component controls the visibility of the dialog, i.e. the event handlers of the parent component both opens and closed the component. E.g. partial code of the parent component is:

```
const ParentComponent = ({}) => {

    const [searchActive, setSearchActive] = useState(false);

    const handleSearchObject = (event) => {
        setSearchActive(true); 
    }

    const handleSearchCancel = (event) => {
        setSearchActive(false);
    }

    const handleSearchSelect = (event) => {
        setSearchActive(false);
        onChangeObject(createEmployeeDavid());
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={handleSearchObject}>Search and Select</Button>
            <DialogCheck
                id={`${id}_check`} 
                emmployee={employee ? employee : null} 
                active={searchActive} 
                onCancel={handleSearchCancel} 
                onSelect={handleSearchSelect}  
            />
        </>
    );
};
```

Of course, if the user clicks 'Search and Select', then the dialog is open and when the user closes dialog with 'Select' or 'Cancel', then dialog becomes invisible. That is fine.

But and can see (using Developer Tools/Web Console), that `div.MuiDialog-container.MuiDialog-scrollPaper` or `div.MuiDialog-container.MuiDialog-scrollPaper` element stays existing/visible/active (one or another depending on the `<Dialog scroll="...">`), while this element is transparent, it effectively bloks any interaction with the active area of the browser page, no futher clicks can be made, no page scrolls, no edit.

Even furhter, on can move the curosor over the active area and see that there are no active regions, except for the spots where the buttons of the (invisible!) dialog are.

So - how can I close the dialog completely. I think that my solution with the component is very nice - user can perform the employee search multiple times while in the page, so, she can be willing to open, close dialog repeatedly.

I have always thought that `<Dialog open="...">` determines completely the activity of the dialog, but apparently more actions are needed to close the dialog gracefully.

What suggestions can be to realise the closing of the dialog effectively?

Comment: Could you provide a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) I was not able to recreate the issue you described on my own

Comment: Indeed, I should put my question on hold. I recreated the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-darkness-hkls9z?file=/src/App.js (it is not working on Chrome, but it is working on FF) and I can open and close dialog in both cases - when the dialog component is in the top level of application and also in the case when the dialog component sits it parent component. So, there is something about the context I have...

Comment: Seems to be https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32286 related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it appears to be a complex bug which is described in https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32286 and whose hack-solution/workaround is mentioned there:

```
div.MuiModal-root:has(> div[style*="opacity: 0"]) {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

That issues alse details alternative and more general hacks.

Comment: Thanks. This was the right workaround, the easy way is just add this css rule to muiTheme -> components -> MuiDialog -> styleOverrides ->  root